# TYPO3: indexed_search, disable indexing for certain controller actions

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase

I have a plugion for a form with 2 action (2 different templates):

- ShowForm.html
- Success.html (when the form has be submitted)

The issue is that both are being indexed by the search engine. I only want the form itself (ShowForm.html) to appear in the search results.

Is there a way to disable indexing for specific actions ? I this case I could prevent the "success" action from being indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the markers `<!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->` and `<!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->` like this:

```
This part is indexed
...
<!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->
...
Your template which should not be indexed
...
<!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->
...
This part is indexed again
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that the page URL with some GET parameters were indexed in addition to the page itself without parameters.

To prevent indexing of the page with URL parameters, I disabled indexing in my controller action in TYPO3 v10 by setting:

```
//disable indexing of this page in indexed_search
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['config']['index_enable'] = 0;
```

---

I've opened a feature request for an official API: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/100465